# data: 'Failed to deserialize params.x - BINDINGS: mandatory field missing at position 47'

Tags: coded-ui-tests, gauge

i'm using gauge automated ui tests with taiko integration written in javascript.
I cant find a way to solve my problem. Here is the error i got.

```
message: 'Invalid parameters',
data: 'Failed to deserialize params.x - BINDINGS: mandatory field missing at position 47'
}
}
        Error Message: transport is closing
        Stacktrace:
```

Here is my step_implementation.js file

```
//this step works fine
step("Go to <item>", async(item) => {
    await goto(item);
    await click($(".fancybox-close-small"))
})
//this step works fine
step("Search for <item>", async(item) => {
    await click(textBox(""));
    await focus($(".pw-search-input"));
    await write(item);
})
//this step does not working, my tests fail while last step accomplished.
step("Go to Product Detail <item> By Index", async(item)=>
{ 
  click(($(".pw-autocomplete-product-suggestion").elements())[item]);  
})  

step("Select the size <item> by index", async(item)=>
{
  click(dropDown({'name':'options'}).elements()[item]);
  click(await $(".detail__add2cart"));
})
```

This my example.spec file

```
## Go to site
//lets say example.com
* Go to "example.com"
* Search for "ERKEK SPOR AYAKKABI KİNETİX"
* Go to Product Detail "1" By Index
```

Answer (score 0):

`click` is an async function and hence has to be awaited, try updating the steps as below

```
step("Go to Product Detail <item> By Index", async(item)=>
{ 
 await click(($(".pw-autocomplete-product-suggestion").elements())[item]);  
})  

step("Select the size <item> by index", async(item)=>
{
  await click(dropDown({'name':'options'}).elements()[item]);
  await click(await $(".detail__add2cart"));
})
```